# Foreach statement on subviews doesn't seem to filter out what needs filtering out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop

My `for` statement seems to be returning more than it should be, and causing an error.  Here is the code...

```
for (BookCustomCell *bcc in [self.tableView subviews])
{
    if (bcc.rowIDTag == [bookID intValue])
    {
        //Do something here.
    }
}
```

As I step through this everything seems to be fine.  It goes through the For statement four times, and each time `bcc.rowIDTag` exists and has a value.  It then goes through it a fifth time.  `bcc.rowIDTag` does not exist and as a result it crashes (SIGABRT).

1. Why would it be going through a fifth time?
2. Conceptually, what am I missing?  (The way I understand things it finds all the
   BookCustomCells in the tableView subviews and then iterates through each of them.  Is that correct?)
3. Is there a better way to accomplish my goal? (I have a tableview with multiple rows.  Each
   row has multiple buttons which are in a custom cell.  When I click a button I need to act upon all of the other buttons within that one row/cell.)

(None of this programming stuff is coming easy for me, but I'm bound and determined to learn it. Thanks for your help.)

Comment: Your BookCustomCell should have the responsibility for changing the buttons it contains, so have a method on that which affects the buttons and call that once you have the selected cell. No need to loop through everything - that's inefficient and asking for trouble!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong, `UITableView` contains some subviews that are not `UITableViewCell`'s, that's why you're getting SIGABRT crashes.

```
for (BookCustomCell *bcc in [self.tableView visibleCells])
{
    if (bcc.rowIDTag == [bookID intValue])
    {
        //Do something here.
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to apply methods to a class that isn't BookCustomCell, this should be better for you.

```
for (UIView*tmp in [self.tableView subviews])
{
   if ([tmp isKindOfClass:BookCustomCell])
   {
      BookCustomCell *bcc = (BookCustomCell*) tmp;
      if (bcc.rowIDTag == [bookID intValue])
      {
         //Do something here.
      }
   }
}
```

Here we take all the views, check to see if it is a BookCustomCell, if it is, apply your code.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you may be modifying `subviews` during the loop. Is that correct? You cannot modify the array during fast enumeration. SIGABRT means an exception is thrown. If you look in your console log, I suspect you will see something like "mutation during enumeration."

If you need to modify the array, you need to make a copy first:

```
NSArray *subviews = [[self.tableView subviews] copy];
for (BookCustomCell *bcc in subviews) {
   ...
}
[subviews release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that SIGABRT arises because there is either no fifth `bcc`, either the fifth `bcc` doesn't have the `rowIDTag` property. So try adding a check if `rowIDTag` exists or isn't equal to nil.

I've never done it the way you did, but if I'd have to iterate through all the cells I'd fo the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:yourSectionHere]; i++) {
  BookCustomCell *bcc = (BookCustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:yourIndexPathHere];
  if (bcc.rowIDTag && bcc.rowIDTag == [bookID intValue] {
    //do your stuff here
  }
}
```

I don't have a Mac nearby, so there might be an error or typing mistake or...

Hope it helps